# Looking for EF4 compatible T4 templates

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, t4, edmx

I'm using EF4 and have a requirement to use stored procedures.  I have successfully mapped my hand-written procedures to my edmx model and it works great. Now i'm ready to build out procedures for my entire schema.  I'd like to generate those stored procedures via T4 templates from my edmx model.  I see a number of dated blog posts concerning this but the links are broken and the pictures are missing so it's hard to see the examples.  If anyone has any T4 templates that generate stored procedures that are compatible with EF4 (identity inserts don't take output parameters for example).  Once I get these templates created, I'll post them somewhere findable so others in this situation can same some time.

Answer (score 1):

I will have more luck if you search for SQL tool, [T4 template](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/01/how-to-use-t4-to-generate-crud-stored-procedures/) or [script](http://www.sqlbook.com/SQL-Server/Auto-generate-CRUD-Stored-Procedures-40.aspx) which can create CRUD stored procedures from existing database tables. You will probably have to modify these helpers to satisfy your needs but in case of template or script it should not be so hard. You will generally get the same result as possible with such theoretical T4 template.

I think the really working template for creating stored procedures from entities doesn't exist because entity can consist from multiple tables and in such case you need stored procedure modifying all those tables - and that is a problem because in publicly exposed API you have access to tables definition and entity definitions but not to mapping between them so you don't know how to create body of such stored procedure. Because of that T4 templates most probably can only generate stored procedures from table definitions and the result is same as using tool doing this directly from the database.